# Highlighting strings between [ and ] in lstlistings

Tags: listings

I want to use `lstlisting` to present a file like this:

```
#comment
[keyword]
key1=value1
key2=value with RegEx

[keyword:NewKeyword]
key1 = value1
key2=value with RegEx
```

and this is my language definition:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{myLang}{
    sensitive=false,
    morestring=[b]",
    keywords={=},
    morecomment=[l]{\#},
}
```

How can I extract `[keyword]` and `[keyword:NewKeyword]`?

Comment: Note that "highlighting" and "extracting" can mean two completely different things. I'm assuming you mean the former - *highlighting*.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 9):

I you want to highlight the words with the `[...]`, you can use `moredelim` (as with `myLangStyleA`) which discards the delimiters and applies the given style. If you want to keep the brackets you can use `morecomment` (as with `myLangStyleB`)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}% only need to provide the file foo.mylang

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.mylang}% provide file foo.mylang
    #comment
    [keyword]
    key1=value1
    key2=value with RegEx

    [keyword:NewKeyword]
    key1 = value1
    key2=value with RegEx
\end{filecontents*}

\lstdefinelanguage{myLang}{
    sensitive=false,
    morestring=[b]",
    keywords={=},
    morecomment=[l]{\#},
}

\lstdefinestyle{myLangStyleA}{
    language=myLang,
    moredelim=[is][\color{blue}\ttfamily]{[}{]}
}

\lstdefinestyle{myLangStyleB}{
    language=myLang,
    morecomment=[s][\color{red}\ttfamily]{[}{]}, 
}

\begin{document}
    Using \textbf{style=myLangStyleA}:
    \lstinputlisting[style=myLangStyleA]{foo.mylang}

    Using \textbf{style=myLangStyleB}:
    \lstinputlisting[style=myLangStyleB]{foo.mylang}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to keep the brackets: the settings seems that of configuration files.

Comment: @egreg: Ok. Have updated the solution that provides both options.