# How to render XML tag brackets bold with listings package?

Tags: listings, xml

I'm currently using the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package to render my XML snippets. The default XML language settings recognize elements, attribute and text properly and my style is set to render tag names **bold**, however, I'd like to see the tag surrounding brackets in a **bold** font face.

So by default a tag is rendered like this: <**html**> but I'd like it like **<.html>** (I had to add the . to fool the syntax highlighting). Do you have any ideas how to do that?

I know I could use [`minted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted), but I have long snippets than run over more than one page and I also need line wrapping which is AFAIK not supported by `minted`.

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. Also include some XML code -- best if you can use `filecontents`.  See [highlighting strings between and in lstlistings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35167/highlighting-strings-between-and-in-lstlistings/35173#35173) for an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Mico's answer to using bold italic text inside listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27677/4301), there is no boldfaced mono spaced font in the Computer Modern font family, so you need to use a font that has a bold mono spaced font.

Borrowing from this earlier question on
[XML syntax highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10255/xml-syntax-highlighting),
here is an example:

[image]

### Known Issues:

- I am not sure why the very first non-comment `<` was not being highlighted.

  Matthias's suggested that this behavior can be overcome by using an `escapechar` and replacing the first `<` with `!\color{red}{<}!` where `!` is the `escapechar`.  This has been incorporated into the solution below.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape,
  breaklines=true,
}

\lstdefinelanguage{XML}{
  morestring=[b][\color{brown}]",
  morestring=[s][\color{red}\bfseries]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  identifierstyle=\color{blue},
  keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
  escapechar=!,
  morekeywords={name,use,xmlns,version,type}% list your attributes here,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=XML]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
!\color{red}\bfseries<!xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="points">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="point">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

---

### Alternate Solution:

Using the solution form [ttfamily with bfseries or how to enable bold in fixed width font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33041/4301) you can use the courier font with

```
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
```

but I personally find these results no so satisfying:

[image]

### Code:

Same as above but delete `\usepackage{pxfonts}` and add:

```
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
```

Comment: Thanks, works like charm (besides the known issue with the first bracket. I'm curious why the colon (which separates the prefix and the localname) is printed black and not blue?

Comment: Hmmm.. I assume it because it is not a normal alphanumeric character so have a different catcode. I tried to adjust that but have not been able to get that character to change color. Perhaps a follow up question?

Comment: @Matthias: Thanks for the fix to the first `<` issue. I have incorporated that into the answer.

Comment: @PeterGrill: And thanks for your answer to the question :)